# When are Carnot groups negatively curved and homeomorphic to Euclidean space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, metric-spaces, sub-riemannian-geometry

When are Carnot groups complete and negatively curved (in the sense of [$CAT(\kappa)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space) spaces)?

Comment: Only abelian ones. It's a theorem of Pauls that a nonabelian simply connected nilpotent groups can't even QI embed into any CAT(0) space.

Comment: Interesting!  This i did not know.

Comment: Abelian Carnot groups are isometric to Euclidean spaces. So no, they're not negatively curved (in dimension $\ge 2$) although they're non-positively curved.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this paper, by any chance?

Comment: *Scott D. Pauls. The large scale geometry in nilpotent Lie groups.
Commun. Anal. Geom. 9(5), 951-982, 2001.* However, the result that every Carnot group of dimension $\ge 2$ is not CAT($-\kappa$) for $\kappa>0$ is straightforward. Indeed, since it has a non-isometric self-homothety, it would imply that it is CAT($-\kappa'$) for every $\kappa'>0$, and hence CAT($-\infty$), which for a geodesic space means an $\mathbf{R}$-tree, which cannot have any subset homeomorphic to the plane.

Comment: PS I don't know if it's part of the question but all Carnot groups are complete, since they have all closed balls compact. In general, any metric space with a transitive isometry group, and having a compact subset with nonempty interior, is complete (easy exercise).

Comment: Amazing, if you want to post the exact same comment as an answer I'd be more than happy to accept.  Also, I'll try out the exercise :)

Comment: @YCor I think it is better to make an answer from your comment, so the question will not appear in "unanswered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Carnot groups are complete metric spaces, since they have all closed balls compact ("proper" metric space). In general, any metric space with a transitive isometry group, and having a compact subset with nonempty interior, is complete (easy exercise).

The result that every Carnot group of dimension $\ge 2$ is not CAT($−\kappa$) for any $\kappa>0$ is straightforward. Indeed, since it has a non-isometric self-homothety, it would imply that it is CAT($−\kappa'$) for every $\kappa'>0$, and hence CAT($-\infty$), which for a geodesic space means an $\mathbf{R}$-tree, which cannot have any subset homeomorphic to the plane.

Actually, a non-abelian Carnot group is not even CAT(0), and does not even have a quasi-isometric embedding into any CAT(0) space (or any uniformly convex Banach space). The latter fact was established in:

Scott D. Pauls. The large scale geometry in nilpotent Lie groups. Commun. Anal. Geom. 9(5), 951-982, 2001. However,